# Access element in array

Tags: solidity

i can access element of integer array but in string array i get error why?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.1 <0.9.0;
contract myArray{
uint[]  ipadProPrice=[1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500];
string []  appleProduct=["ipad","macbook","iphone"];
uint public accessElement=ipadProPrice[5];
uint public accessElementS=appleProduct[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `accessElementS` variable is of type `uint`. It should be of type `string`:

```js
contract myArray{
    uint[]  ipadProPrice=[1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500];
    string []  appleProduct = ["ipad","macbook","iphone"];
    uint public accessElement = ipadProPrice[5];
    string public accessElementS = appleProduct[1];
}
```